# What's the purpose of the <Snippet> tag in a Google Earth KML file?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am writing a program that generates KML files, but I can't find a good description or documentation for what the `<Snippet>` tag is actually used for. Does it get displayed in Google Earth?

Answer (score 0):

> A short description of the feature. In Google Earth, this description
>   is displayed in the Places panel under the name of the feature. If a
>   Snippet is not supplied, the first two lines of the `<description>` are
>   used. In Google Earth, if a Placemark contains both a description and
>   a Snippet, the `<Snippet>` appears beneath the Placemark in the Places
>   panel, and the `<description>` appears in the Placemark's description
>   balloon. This tag does not support HTML markup. `<Snippet>` has a
>   maxLines attribute, an integer that specifies the maximum number of
>   lines to display.

source: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

Comment: Typically if a description is long and/or contains rich HTML markup the snippet field can make the display in the places panel short and clean allowing a user to click a given placemark for full details.

Comment: As mentioned above, snippet is used to customize the "subtitle" text in the Places/list view, from the default "first 2 lines of the description". For me, it's probably most useful for inserting an EMPTY snippet tag, which removes the "subtitle" line, and keeps it from displaying content from the description.  Also note that this applies to Google Earth Pro, and not to the new Google Earth (v9+) for Web, Android and iOS, since that currently does not show any subtitle text in the "My Places" or list view.